# Swipe for page transitions?

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, navigation, swipe

I'm trying to use swipe for page navigation, but the code I have seems to be broken. This is only my second app and I would love some help. I'm having trouble pasting my code here, but I've uploaded what I have on the school server, so you can pull the source code from there -

dtc-wsuv.org/jcohen/strings

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your source code, you can try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live` since `live` is deprecated in jQuery version 1.7 as well as wrapping your code inside `$(document).ready(function() { })` or `$(function() { })` to let jQuery see the whole DOM, so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.swipe').on("swipeleft", function () {
    var nextpage = $(this).next('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (nextpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, "slide", false, true);
    }
});

$('.swipe').on("swiperight", function () {                                          
    var prevpage = $(this).prev('div[data-role="page"]');
    if (prevpage.length > 0) {
        $.mobile.changePage(prevpage, {
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: true
        }, true, true);
    }
});
})
```